# Regular expression seach fails in MS Word table

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I'm using this expression to execute a Find in Word for Office 365, using wildcards:

```
([0-9.]@)E([-+0-9]@)([!0-9])
```

In a table cell I have the following text:

```
1.1E-4
```

But this returns "couldn't find any matches": However, if the same text is outside the table, i.e. in a paragraph, the Find succeeds. I can't figure out why and I can't find any references to this phenomenon anywhere.

Can anyone help me find what the reason for this might be?

Comment: It's astonishing that you get any hits. As far as I know Word doesn't support regular expressions by default. As an example it doesn't work on my installation. Depending on how you include the table it might also be a case of having to search across object boundaries. If it's an Excel table it's not part of the regular document but rather something that starts Excel to display the table (in a simplified manner). You would probably have to go into more detail as to how you included that table.

Comment: @seth You may be in for a pleasant surprise, see [Using wildcards - Microsoft Word 2016](https://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/using_wildcards.html)

Comment: Based on the help I got below, I've tried, successfully `([0-9.]@)E([-+0-9]@)([0-9]{2})` which catches 1.4E05, but `([0-9.]@)E([-+0-9]@)([0-9]{2,})` throws me and error (pattern expression is not valid), so I can't get 1.3E-123 for example. I thought [0-9]{2,} should be supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is simple. The last part of the search expression is `([!0-9])` which means that it matches a non digit. In a table cell after `1.1E-4` you have no additional characters for this expression to match. Outside the table you probably have a paragraph mark that matches this last part of the search expression.

If you add a paragraph mark (or e.g. a space) in the table cell this expression will match. For some reason end of cell marker is not a character you can search for (for example see this short discussion: http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?p=494839).

Comment: Ok I see, that makes sense. Then I have something to work with. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: If I know that the string I'm looking forward always ends with a number [0-9] I could use this, and then do my maniputation and replace with the same character, right? To be clear, I'm trying to convert numbers in tables pasted from Excel scientific notation (2.3E-04) to 'normal' scientific notation in the form 2.3 x 10^-4 with the -4 in superscript. I will keep trying.

Comment: Based on your inpp, I've tried, successfully ([0-9.]@)E([-+0-9]@)([0-9]{2}) which catches 1.4E05, but ([0-9.]@)E([-+0-9]@)([0-9]{2,}) throws me and error (pattern expression is not valid), so I can't get 1.3E-123 for example. I thought [0-9]{2,} should be supported?

Comment: Ok found it myself. In swedish locale the separator should be `;` not `,` i.e. `([0-9.]@)E([-+0-9]@)([0-9]{2;3})`. Now it works as anticipated.

Comment: I wrote about it here for those interested: [link](http://jesperknutsson.com/tools/auto-format-excel-scientific-notation-in-word/)